# Google Cloud Storage ACL troubles

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have a bucket on Google Cloud Storage that I created. I wanted to test some of the built in ACLs like public-read, public-read-write, etc. But once I changed the ACL using the gsutil setacl command like so:
`gsutil setacl public-read-write gs://mybucket`
I seem to have lost the ability to set the ACL to anything else, I also can not get the current ACL. When I attempt either I get the following message:
`GSResponseError: status=403, code=AccessDenied, reason=Forbidden, detail=mybucket.`

Not sure if this is a bug or I am just missing something obvious. How do I regain the ability to set the ACLs?

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://code.google.com/apis/console/#:team and see whether you are a viewer, editor or owner of the project.

1. Contact one of the owners of the project.
2. Ask the owner to run `gsutil chacl -u you@gmail.com:FC gs://mybucket` or else make you an owner of the project.

Project owners always have full control of buckets.

Comment: Thanks for the chacl suggestion, but are you suggesting that this is normal behavior for anyone other than owners? I'm an editor, btw, and this happens for buckets that I create. Why would setting an acl as I did strip me of access to the bucket? Forcing the owners to be involved with each editor's changes doesn't seem like a good development strategy moving forward.